Large nextjs docker image
So im building this Dockerfile to deploy my nextjs application. Now this dockerfile should build a production nextjs application. But my docker image is rather large 2.3gb. Here is my Dockerfile.
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY public ./public
COPY app ./app
COPY components ./components
COPY ./lib /app/lib
COPY next.config.js ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./
COPY tailwind.config.ts ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY middleware.ts ./
COPY next-env.d.ts ./
COPY components.json ./
COPY auth.config.ts ./
COPY auth.ts ./
COPY postcss.config.js ./

RUN npm run build

RUN npm prune --production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]

Also I know i can switch to an alpine image but I dont think this will decrease the image size much. Thanks in advance
EDIT
0   ADD file:b7c55dda8ded4219a7cdc9fbd91dfb5996c4886d4394b85751c2f956defe3287 in /                                                                                                              138.89 MB
1   CMD ["bash"]                                                                                                                                                                                  0 B
2   set -eux; apt-get update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl gnupg netbase sq wget ; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                48.48 MB
3   set -eux; apt-get update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git mercurial openssh-client subversion procps ; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                            182.66 MB
4   set -ex; apt-get update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends autoconf automake bzip2 default-libmysqlclient-dev dpkg-dev file g++ gcc imagemagick libbz2-dev libc6-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdb-dev libevent-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libglib2.0-dev libgmp-dev libjpeg-dev libkrb5-dev liblzma-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmaxminddb-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libpng-dev libpq-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libwebp-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libyaml-dev make patch unzip xz-utils zlib1g-dev ; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*    559.9 MB
5   groupadd --gid 1000 node && useradd --uid 1000 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node                                                                                                8.94 KB
6   ENV NODE_VERSION=18.20.3                                                                                                                                                                       0 B
7   ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in amd64) ARCH='x64';; ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';; s390x) ARCH='s390x';; arm64) ARCH='arm64';; armhf) ARCH='armv7l';; i386) ARCH='x86';; *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;; esac && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" && set -ex && for key in 4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C 141F07595B7B3FFE74309A937405533BE57C7D57 74F12602B6F1C4E913FAA37AD3A89613643B6201 DD792F5973C6DE52C432CBDAC77ABFA00DDBF2B7 61FC681DFB92A079F1685E77973F295594EC4689 8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 890C08DB8579162FEE0DF9DB8BEAB4DFCF555EF4 C82FA3AE1CBEDC6BE46B9360C43CEC45C17AB93C 108F52B48DB57BB0CC439B2997B01419BD92F80A A363A499291CBBC940DD62E41F10027AF002F8B0 CC68F5A3106FF448322E48ED27F5E38D5B0A215F ; do gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$key" || gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key" ; done && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc && gpgconf --kill all && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs && node --version && npm --version  154 MB
8   ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19                                                                                                                                                                        0 B
9   set -ex && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" && for key in 6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 ; do gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$key" || gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key" ; done && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz && gpgconf --kill all && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" && mkdir -p /opt && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz && yarn --version && rm -rf /tmp/* 5.33 MB
10  COPY file:4d192565a7220e135cab6c77fbc1c73211b69f3d9fb37e62857b2c6eb9363d51 in /usr/local/bin/                                                                                                    388 B
11  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]                                                                                                                                                             0 B
12  CMD ["node"]                                                                                                                                                                                    0 B
13  WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                    0 B
14  COPY package*.json ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                           350.22 KB
15  RUN /bin/sh -c npm install # buildkit                                                                                                                                                      713.24 MB
16  COPY public ./public # buildkit                                                                                                                                                             29.51 KB
17  COPY app ./app # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                   884.7 KB
18  COPY components ./components # buildkit                                                                                                                                                    150.32 KB
19  COPY ./lib /app/lib # buildkit                                                                                                                                                               19.07 KB
20  COPY next.config.js ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                              360 B
21  COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                           221.58 KB
22  COPY tailwind.config.ts ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                         2.27 KB
23  COPY tsconfig.json ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                709 B
24  COPY middleware.ts ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                208 B
25  COPY next-env.d.ts ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                201 B
26  COPY components.json ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                              342 B
27  COPY auth.config.ts ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                               997 B
28  COPY auth.ts ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                     1.26 KB
29  COPY postcss.config.js ./ # buildkit                                                                                                                                                             82 B
30  RUN /bin/sh -c npm run build # buildkit                                                                                                                                                    425.76 MB
31  RUN /bin/sh -c npm prune --production # buildkit                                                                                                                                             574.88 KB
32  EXPOSE map[3000/tcp:{}]                                                                                                                                                                          0 B
33  CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]                                                                                                                                     0 B

Here are the layers. Its not my nextjs app im just deploying but whenever I do npm install --production in the dockerfile I get errors from missing packages. Assuming some (a lot) necessary packages are in devdependencies.

Do you know where the space is actually going?  Note that deleting files from an image doesn't actually reduce the image size, because the previous layers that contained the files are still part of the image; if you have substantial devDependencies, the npm prune step won't usefully remove them from the image.

I added the layers, looks like npm install and npm run build are the largest. But these are necessary so how can you decrease the size of a production build nextjs docker app?

is npm installing a lot of dependencies?  How large is the node_modules directory?

Its around 450mb, but i have been able to reduce the image size to half by using multi stage dockerfile.

By using an Alpine build and using a multi stage dockerfile i have been able to reduce the image size to half.
# Stage 1: Build Stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY public ./public
COPY app ./app
COPY components ./components
COPY lib ./lib
COPY next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY tailwind.config.ts ./tailwind.config.ts
COPY tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json
COPY middleware.ts ./middleware.ts
COPY next-env.d.ts ./next-env.d.ts
COPY components.json ./components.json
COPY auth.config.ts ./auth.config.ts
COPY auth.ts ./auth.ts
COPY postcss.config.js ./postcss.config.js

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Final Stage
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app /app
RUN npm prune --production

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]

